# Using forever command to run node.js script on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, heroku

So, I searched a lot before asking this here as I was not able to find a single answer related to this small problem.

I want to run node.js file on my heroku server which is on free-tier but I don't want to use `node file.js`. I want to use `forever start file.js`.

So, I did wrote the commands in my package files as well as defined a Procfile for `worker: forever start file.js`.

And deployed to heroku, but all the logs says that 
`forever: bash command not found`.

Any solution ?

Comment: Do you add it to your package.json dependencies ?

Comment: I added code to run in "scripts" section.

Comment: Yes I get that, but have you referenced forever in your dependencies ?

Comment: Ok, I have not. Let me try that and will tell you then.

Comment: Well, after adding forever dependencies in my package.json it isntalled forever and executed the command but still the worker script is not being executed . It just keeps on repeating the same command again and again.